# When I write again in file with openCsv, this file is overwritten

Tags: java, csv, opencsv

When I try to write data to a file with opencsv, the file is overwritten instead. All previous data is erased and retains the last data. I used this tutorial http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/#can-I-write , but it didn't help.

```
        case 3:
            CSVReader reader = new CSVReader(new FileReader(file));
            if (reader.readNext()==null) { 
                reader.close();
                CSVWriter writer = new CSVWriter(new FileWriter(file));
                String[]entries="first#second#third".split("#");
                writer.writeNext(entries);
                writer.close();
            }
            CSVWriter writer = new CSVWriter(new FileWriter(file),',');
            String[]entries = new String[7];
            System.out.print("Введите Фамилию(обязательно): ");
            entries[0]=check(br.readLine());
            System.out.print("Введите имя(обязательно): ");
            entries[1]=check(br.readLine());
            System.out.print("Введите Отчество(обязательно): ");
            entries[2]=check(br.readLine());
            System.out.print("Введите телефон мобильный(обязательно): ");
            entries[3]=check(br.readLine());
            System.out.print("Введите телефон домашний: ");
            entries[4]=br.readLine();
            System.out.print("Введите адресс: ");
            entries[5]=br.readLine();
            System.out.print("Введите e-mail: ");
            entries[6]=br.readLine();
            writer.writeNext(entries);
                writer.close();
            break;
```

What should I do to fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you read the [javadoc for `FileWriter`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileWriter.html) you will get the answer.

`FileWriter` has a constructor which allows to append to a file: `FileWriter(File file, boolean append)`

Answer (score 1):

You can create a CSV Writer as

```
CSVWriter csvwriter = new CSVWriter(new FileWriter(file, true));
```